# Getting parent for kobject_add

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

Is there any simple method for getting parent to use in kobject_add function? I want to put the file in `/sys/module/mymodule/parameters`. I've got already working parameter, but I create it in wrong directory. I've found that there is module_subsys in module.h, but I have no idea how to use it. 
It's my code for init function:

```
static int __init init_hello(void)
{
    subsystem_register(&module_subsys);
     struct my_attr *a;
    Major = misc_register(&mydevice);
     mykobj = kzalloc(sizeof(*mykobj), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (mykobj) {
            kobject_init(mykobj, &mytype);
            kobj_set_kset_s(mykobj, module_subsys);
            if (kobject_add(mykobj, NULL, "%s", "sysfs_example")) {
                    printk("Sysfs creation failed\n");
                    kobject_put(mykobj);
                    mykobj = NULL;
                    return -1;
                    }
        }


     a = container_of(&(my_first.attr), struct my_attr, attr);
    msg_Ptr = kzalloc(a->value, GFP_KERNEL);
    bytesindev=0;
    if(Major) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Rejestrowanie urządzenia nie powiodło się\n");
        return Major;

    }


    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried it myself, but `&THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj` looks appropriate.
I didn't see any kernel code that uses `kobject_add` directly with this, so perhaps it isn't the right way.

If you've registered a device driver, then `&dev->kobj` looks like a good way.

Comment: I've found it also myself a few minutes ago while looking at module.h, the version with THIS_MODULE works for me

Comment: But in my kernel kobj attribute is not a pointer, so it shold look like &THIS_MODULE->mkobj.kobj

Comment: My mistake. I didn't actually try to compile it. Editing.